# ExecutorService sleep all threads in thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a problem with using `ExecutorService`, ideally I'm looking for a solution to sleep all threads inside of thread pool (playing with Adwords API, when pushing some ads I get rate exceeded error which I catch, and then sleep that thread, but other threads are not aware of that error and still work hitting API with rate exceeded response, which increases the waiting time until another request can be processed).

Is there any simple way to sleep all threads in the same time? I tried to find any solution, I have one in mind but I'm sure there is something similar that exist out there.

Thank you for any help and have a nice day.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748710/how-to-pause-resume-all-threads-in-an-executorservice-in-java

Comment: I dont think there is an option for that but you can make use of PausableThreadPoolExecutor as mentioned on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html page.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for one thread to "sleep" another, and even if it was possible, it's not a good idea.  Threads should *cooperate*.

If you're using an ExecutorService, that means, there is a queue of tasks.  The simplest solution would be to limit the rate at which you put tasks into the queue.

A different solution would be to create a global "throttle" object that all of the tasks know about.  It would have a method that each task can call to wait until it's OK to go.  You'd want to put some thought into how that object was synchronized:  A simple, global lock could be a significant bottleneck if the maximum rate that you are trying to achieve is high.