# ExecutorService make all threads wait

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, executorservice

Is there an simple/elegant way to make all threads created by `ExecutorService` to ***wait()*** ?

My current solution is to add a flag and pause make the threads wait with it like so:

```java
public class task implements Runnable {
        
        static boolean flag;
         
        public void run()
        {
            while(true){
                if(flag){
                    wait();
                }else{
                    /* do stuff */
                    .
                    .
                    .
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But in this way I can only make thread wait at the end of an iteration of its task and It's seem to be unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Search for Java CyclicBarrier or Phaser

Comment: Maybe the answers here are helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748710/how-to-pause-resume-all-threads-in-an-executorservice-in-java